# What does 圆 mean in this context?

Tags: word

只要你成功了有钱了，丑是耐看的，胖是圆润的，矮是精华，黑是质感，什么缺点都圆得过去。
As long as you are successful and become rich, ...(Sorry, I don't understand the rest, especially the word 圆 in 都圆得过去, please help.)

Comment: Tang Ho has answered the main question, but the rest is just examples of shortcomings that can be explained away. I’m not entirely sure what exactly 黑 is in reference to here (perhaps something like skin imperfections or not being 美白 enough?), but they’re all parallel pairs of ‘[negative] → [euphemism]’: _If you just become successful and rich enough, any shortcomings of yours will be glossed over: ‘ugly’ becomes ‘has a special charm’, ‘fat’ becomes ‘soft and smooth’, ‘short’ becomes ‘has a distilled essence’, ‘dark(?)’ becomes ‘has texture’._

Comment: 矮是精华 should be 矮是精猂 (短小精猂) = compact and dynamic"，黑是质感 should be 黑是實感 = "firm"

Comment: 笨是老實，貪是進取，懶是無為，殘忍是有決斷，好色是博愛

Answer (score 4):

圆 as a verb has the meaning "to explain (against doubt or criticism) = to justify"

Example:

自圆其說 = Explain (justify) one's statement (against doubt or criticism)

similar to 狡辯 (quibble) but more elegantly so

> 什么缺点都圆得过去

Can explain away any shortcomings

A real-life example:

It's hard to **justify** banning any book that contains sexual and violent content without banning The Bible

禁止任何包含性和暴力內容的書籍而不禁止聖經是很難**自圆其說**的

Answer (score 1):

> 什么缺点都圆得过去

可以换成 `什么缺点都能说得过去`, 这里的`圆`可以理解为把某一事物的`缺点或不足` 用`好的观点`(or the act of praising someone or say the opposite meaning of "defect")去解释, 比如一个人个子`矮`，对个子`矮`这个事实，如果我们从另外一种角度去理解的话：他为什么矮？有人会说:"`矮是因为浓缩了，浓缩的是精华`".

这里的`浓缩了`中的`浓缩`和`核武器的浓缩铀`(The concentrate uranium in nuclear weapons)中的`浓缩`是一个意思，`浓缩`是因为提纯了，抛弃了杂质，留下的是精华. (Compare the weight, volume, and other properties of the substance before and after concentrate.).

## Update

below explain for comment

> Is this chemical jargon(concentrate or 浓缩) a flattery in Chinese?

I found the meaning of flattery at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/flattery?q=flattery+) is:

```
the act of praising someone, often in a way that is not sincere, because you want something from them
```

I'm surely that "the act of praising someone", maybe that "often in a way that is not sincere", please specify the context(看具体情况或者看说话的目的) that "because you want something from them"，比如只是随意交谈的话，没有任何目的，this chemical jargon(concentrate or 浓缩) **is not** a flattery in Chinese；如果 “because you want something from them”，then this chemical jargon(concentrate or 浓缩) **is** a flattery in Chinese.

**Summarize** for "Is this chemical jargon(concentrate or 浓缩) a flattery in Chinese?":

Whether or not it is depends mainly on the purpose of the speech.

Comment: Being short is a defect, so people will find other words that sound pleasing to say the same thing? You are not short, but you are enriched like a uranium? Is this chemical jargon a flattery in Chinese?

Comment: @NanningYouth "Being short is a defect, so people will find other words that sound pleasing to say the same thing?" answer is YES. "You are not short", should be "You are short", 矮是因为浓缩了, "浓缩"后导致了矮 (because 浓缩是因为提纯了，抛弃了杂质，留下的是精华 ), "enriched like a uranium" is just explain for you. This chemical jargon(enriched ) is other words that sound pleasing to say the same thing(矮)，矮的另外一种解释(or say the opposite meaning of "defect").  I know that civilized people in developed countries are very concerned about using someone's shortcomings as the subject of jokes.

Comment: @NanningYouth please see my updated answer. 说浓缩可以理解为是赞美，但是说奉承就有点过头了.

Comment: Thank you, very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

`圆` in `都圆得过去` means everything `can be covered` or `explained` or `find a good excuse` as long as you are rich.